# Why is Stata smothed hazard estimate pruned to interval?

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival, stata, hazard

I have played through [this R example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958346/6574038) to calculate hazard estimates.

I chased the whole thing through Stata and obtained a different graph, though.

**R graph:** 
[image]

**Stata graph:**
[image]

What's the rationale behind Stata to prune the graph like so?

Here's a brief summary of the data:

```
> summary(ovarian)
     futime           fustat            age           resid.ds           rx         ecog.ps     
 Min.   :  59.0   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :38.89   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.0   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.: 368.0   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:50.17   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:1.0   1st Qu.:1.000  
 Median : 476.0   Median :0.0000   Median :56.85   Median :2.000   Median :1.5   Median :1.000  
 Mean   : 599.5   Mean   :0.4615   Mean   :56.17   Mean   :1.577   Mean   :1.5   Mean   :1.462  
 3rd Qu.: 794.8   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:62.38   3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.:2.0   3rd Qu.:2.000  
 Max.   :1227.0   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :74.50   Max.   :2.000   Max.   :2.0   Max.   :2.000
```

and how the data is declared and plotted in Stata:

```
. stset futime fustat

     failure event:  fustat != 0 & fustat < .
obs. time interval:  (0, futime]
 exit on or before:  failure
...

. sts graph, hazard ci
```

**Edit**

Because the data is not very extensive, here are the full data:

```
> ovarian
   futime fustat     age resid.ds rx ecog.ps
1      59      1 72.3315        2  1       1
2     115      1 74.4932        2  1       1
3     156      1 66.4658        2  1       2
4     421      0 53.3644        2  2       1
5     431      1 50.3397        2  1       1
6     448      0 56.4301        1  1       2
7     464      1 56.9370        2  2       2
8     475      1 59.8548        2  2       2
9     477      0 64.1753        2  1       1
10    563      1 55.1781        1  2       2
11    638      1 56.7562        1  1       2
12    744      0 50.1096        1  2       1
13    769      0 59.6301        2  2       2
14    770      0 57.0521        2  2       1
15    803      0 39.2712        1  1       1
16    855      0 43.1233        1  1       2
17   1040      0 38.8932        2  1       2
18   1106      0 44.6000        1  1       1
19   1129      0 53.9068        1  2       1
20   1206      0 44.2055        2  2       1
21   1227      0 59.5890        1  2       2
22    268      1 74.5041        2  1       2
23    329      1 43.1370        2  1       1
24    353      1 63.2192        1  2       2
25    365      1 64.4247        2  2       1
26    377      0 58.3096        1  2       1
```

Comment: Do any failures occur before analysis time ~ 180?

Comment: @TheLaconic Yes. I've added the full data because it's not very huge.

Comment: Read down in the responses here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1380782-smoothed-hazard-function-with-sts-graph.  That might be a good enough answer for you.  Not sure why R extrapolates the to left so far; it seems like that would always tend toward zero, which isn’t useful.